# Не тот html код по ссылке

Tags: c#

Требуется получить в строку *html код*, формирующийся при переходе по ссылке *https://username.github.io/?action="get"*

Попробовал так:

```
string url = @"https://username.github.io?action=""get"" ";
string content = "";

using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    content = webClient.DownloadString(url).ToString();
}
```

Но в *content*, строка, которая была бы там при *https://username.github.io*. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

PS У меня при переходе по данной ссылке срабатывает js код, который добавляет текст на страницу.

Comment: точно нужны кавычки?

Comment: Дайте нормальную ссылку, с которой можно было бы поработать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таким образом невозможно получить html код, так-как он формируется в js файле. Код JS файла при запросе html кода **не выполняется**.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно Вам нужен [`Uri.EscapeUriString(String)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapeuristring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Uri.EscapeUriString("https://username.github.io/?action="get"")
```

-->

```
"https://username.github.io/?action=%22get%22"
```

PS: кавычки скорее всего не нужны Вам вообще

Comment: Убрал кавычки, и я немного не понимаю, почему если у меня код на C# , а у вас на JS.

Comment: @Andrew мда, и с чего я решил что у Вас js, однако в c# есть аналогичные методы, сейчас поменяю ответ

Comment: К сожалению оно не работает, и я кое о чём случайно умолчал. Сейчас обновлю вопрос.